# Batch file IF condition. Syntax incorrect.

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, conditional-statements

Working with an old system at the moment and have a batch file which does a bunch of work.

Im trying to add an IF condition to compare strings but its just not working for me.

```
SET ENABLED=%1

IF "%ENABLED%"=="n"
(
    echo "doing some work"
)
```

The batch file is executed like

```
MyBatch.bat n
```

However this is resulting in an error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: IIRC, the open parenthesis (`(`) needs to be on the same line as the `if` command, unless you use end the line with an escape (`^`) character. In any case, I would recommend switching to PowerShell - you get very advanced parameter parsing and a _far_ more consistent syntax.

Comment: Move the `(` Up on the line `IF "%ENABLED%"=="n" (`

Answer (score 1):

Batch file (cmd.exe shell script) syntax can be a challenge.

The answer in this case is to keep the open parenthesis (`(`) on the same line as the `if` command.